# Does installing some PostgreSQL options create some related tables?

Tags: postgresql

After restoring an old pgsql database tables I realized that it contains tables like `pg_ts_cfg`, `pg_ts_dict`, `geometry_columns` and `spatial_ref_sys`.

I can't remember creating those tables and I wonder if the presence of features like PostGIS and FTS automatically creates them, or adds them to `template1`?

Is that the most likely reason?

Comment: PostGIS adds `geometry_columns` and `spatial_ref_sys`, by default they're not added to `template1`, especially in the newer versions.

Comment: In old, pre-`EXTENSION` databases it was typical for contrib modules to create tables in `public`. Now you just `CREATE EXTENSION`. If you're updating from an old version DB, look into `CREATE EXTENSION ... FROM UNPACKAGED`